# Admin.js + Nest.js monorepo (ESM and CJS)

Tags: typescript, nestjs, es6-modules, monorepo, adminjs

I want to create a mono repo with 3 folders:

- adminjs
- api
- shared

Adminjs, created with adminjs create (v7 on nest.js). As written in their documents, it only supports ESM.
The api is a simple nest application with mongoose. As I understand it, it only supports CJS.
A shared folder is a folder that contains some nestjs/mongoose utilities and schemas with decorators.

Maybe someone has faced a similar problem.
How to describe package.json and tsconfig to connect a shared folder to each application together. Maybe someone can describe an example please. Or maybe someone sees some available repositories to look at?

*I am grateful to everyone who responds.*

I have already tried to make shared folders for build/esm/... and build/cjs/... But it doesn't help and I have problems after building the main applications. Each time there are different import issues and I can't solve them.

Comment: Maybe NX can solve this problem?

Comment: If you have a link to a repo with your current progress you might get more help.

Comment: I have a lot of test projects, and every of them is not working in any way. So I'm wondering if anyone can give me a direction or an example. Because I'm stuck.